# Unsupported operand type?

Tags: php, operand

I've got to say I am completely clueless in terms of PHP, I know enough to moderate my sites to an acceptable extent. I'm having a bit of trouble with phpauction GPL, whenever I click on one of my categories, I get this:

Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/retrorea/public_html/tradepost/browse.php on line 175

This is what line 175 reads...

```
$left_limit = ($page-1)*$lines;
```

Here's the rest of the code.

```
<?#//v.3.2.3
#///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#// COPYRIGHT 2007 Phpauction.net ALL RIGHTS RESERVED //
#///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

require('./includes/config.inc.php');
include $include_path."auctionstoshow.inc.php";
#// Get parameters from the URL
$params = getUrlParams("=");
if(empty($_GET['id']))
    $_GET['id'] = $params['id'];
else
    $params['id'] = $_GET['id'];
$id = intval($params['id']);

#// #############################################################################
function getsubtree($catsubtree,$i) {
    global $catlist;
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT cat_id FROM PHPAUCTIONXL_categories WHERE parent_id=".intval($catsubtree[$i]));
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $catlist[]=$row['cat_id'];
        $catsubtree[$i+1]=$row['cat_id'];
        getsubtree($catsubtree,$i+1);
    }
}

$catsubtree[0]=$id;
$catlist[]=$catsubtree[0];
getsubtree($catsubtree,0);
$catalist="(";
$catalist.=join(",",$catlist);
$catalist.=")";
$NOW = date("YmdHis",mktime(date("H")+$SETTINGS['timecorrection'],date("i"),date("s"),date("m"), date("d"),date("Y")));
if ($id==0) {
    /*
    display full list of categories of level 0
    */
    $result = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM PHPAUCTIONXL_categories WHERE parent_id='0' ORDER BY cat_name" );
    if (!$result) {
        /* output error message and exit */
        print "database error";
        exit;
    } else {
        /* query succeeded - display list of categories */
        $need_to_continue = 1;
        $cycle = 1;

        $TPL_main_value = "";
        $TPL_categories_string = $MGS_2__0027;
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($cycle==1 ) {
                $TPL_main_value.="<tr WIDTH=100% ALIGN=LEFT>\n";
            }
            $sub_counter = (int)$row['sub_counter'];
            $cat_counter = (int)$row['counter'];
            if ($sub_counter!=0) $count_string = "(".$sub_counter.")";
            else {
                $count_string = "";
            }
            #// Retrieve the translated category name
            $row['cat_name'] = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT cat_name FROM PHPAUCTIONXL_cats_translated WHERE cat_id=".$row['cat_id']." AND lang='".$language."'"),0,"cat_name");
            $TPL_main_value .=!empty($row['cat_colour']) ? "    <td BGCOLOR=\"".$row['cat_colour']."\" WIDTH=\"33%\"><a href=\"".$SETTINGS['siteurl']."browse.php?id=".$row['cat_id']."\">".$row['cat_name'].$count_string."</a></td>\n" : "    <td WIDTH=\"33%\"><a href=\"".$SETTINGS['siteurl']."browse.php?id=".$row['cat_id']."\">".$row['cat_name'].$count_string."</a></td>\n";

            ++$cycle;
            if ($cycle==4) { $cycle=1; $TPL_main_value.="</tr>\n"; }
        }

        if ( $cycle>=2 && $cycle<=3 ) {
            while ( $cycle<4 ) {
                $TPL_main_value .= "    <td WIDTH=\"33%\">&nbsp;</td>\n";
                ++$cycle;
            }
            $TPL_main_value .= "</tr>\n";
        }
        $TPL_auctions_list_value = array();

    $PAGE = 1;
    $PAGES = 1;

        include "header.php";
        include phpa_include("template_browse_header_php.html");
        include phpa_include("template_browse_php.html");
        include "footer.php";
        exit;
    }
} else {
    /*
    specified category number

    look into table - and if we don't have such category - redirect to full list
    */
    $result = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM PHPAUCTIONXL_categories WHERE cat_id=".intval($id) );
    if ($result)
    $category = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    else
    $category = false;
    #// Retrieve the translated category name
    $category['cat_name'] = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT cat_name FROM PHPAUCTIONXL_cats_translated WHERE cat_id=".$category['cat_id']." AND lang='".$language."'"),0,"cat_name");
    if (!$category) {
        /* redirect to global categories list */
        header ( "Location: browse.php?id=0" );
        exit;
    } else {
        /*
        such category exists
        retrieve it's subcategories and its auctions
        */
        /* recursively get "path" to this category */

        $TPL_categories_string = "".$category["cat_name"];
        $par_id = (int)$category['parent_id'];

        while ( $par_id!=0 ) {
            // get next parent
            $res = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM PHPAUCTIONXL_categories WHERE cat_id=".intval($par_id));
            if ($res) {
                $rw = mysql_fetch_array($res);
                if ($rw) $par_id = (int)$rw['parent_id'];
                else $par_id = 0;
            } else $par_id = 0;
            #// Retrieve the translated category name
            $rw['cat_name'] = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT cat_name FROM PHPAUCTIONXL_cats_translated WHERE cat_id=".$rw['cat_id']." AND lang='".$language."'"),0,"cat_name");
            $TPL_categories_string = "<a href=\"".$SETTINGS['siteurl']."browse.php?id=".$rw["cat_id"]."\">".$rw["cat_name"]."</a> &gt; ".$TPL_categories_string;
        }

        /* get list of subcategories of this category */
        $subcat_count = 0;
        $result = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM PHPAUCTIONXL_categories WHERE parent_id=".intval($id)." ORDER BY cat_name" );
        if (!$result) {
            /* output error message and exit */
        } else {
            /* query succeeded - display list of categories */
            $need_to_continue = 1;
            $cycle = 1;

            $TPL_main_value = "";
            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                ++$subcat_count;
                if ($cycle==1 ) {
                    $TPL_main_value.="<tr ALIGN=LEFT>\n";
                }
                $sub_counter = (int)$row['sub_counter'];
                $cat_counter = (int)$row['counter'];
                if ($sub_counter!=0) $count_string = "(".$sub_counter.")";
                else {
                    if ($cat_counter!=0) {
                        $count_string = "(".$cat_counter.")";
                    } else $count_string = "";
                }
                if($row['cat_colour'] != "") {
                    $BG ="BGCOLOR=".$row['cat_colour'];
                } else {
                    $BG = "";
                }
                #// Retrieve the translated category name
                $row['cat_name'] = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT cat_name FROM PHPAUCTIONXL_cats_translated WHERE cat_id=".$row['cat_id']." AND lang='".$language."'"),0,"cat_name");
                $TPL_main_value .= "    <td $BG WIDTH=\"33%\"><a href=\"".$SETTINGS['siteurl']."browse.php?id=".$row['cat_id']."\">".$row['cat_name'].$count_string."</a></td>\n";

                ++$cycle;
                if ($cycle==4) {
                    $cycle=1;
                    $TPL_main_value.="</tr>\n";
                }
            }

            if ( $cycle>=2 && $cycle<=3 ) {
                while ( $cycle<4 ) {
                    $TPL_main_value .= "    <td WIDTH=\"33%\">&nbsp;</td>\n";
                    ++$cycle;
                }
                $TPL_main_value .= "</tr>\n";
            }
        }
        /* determine limits for SQL query */
        $left_limit = ($page-1)*$lines;

        /* retrieve records corresponding to passed page number */
        $page = (int)$page;
        if ($page==0)   $page = 1;
        $lines = (int)$lines;
        if ($lines==0)  $lines = 50;

        /* get total number of records */
        $qs = "SELECT count(*) FROM PHPAUCTIONXL_auctions 
                        WHERE category IN $catalist 
                        AND starts<=".$NOW." 
                        AND closed='0' 
                        AND private='n' 
                        AND suspended ='0'";
         if($SETTINGS['adultonly']=='y' && !isset($_SESSION["PHPAUCTION_LOGGED_IN"])){
             $qs .= "AND adultonly='n'";
         }

        if(!empty($_POST['catkeyword'])){
            $qs .= " AND title like '%".addslashes($_POST['catkeyword'])."'%";
        }
        $rsl = mysql_query ($qs);
        if ($rsl) {
            $hash = mysql_fetch_array($rsl);
            $total = !$hash[0] ? 1 : (int)$hash[0];
        } else $total = 1;
        #// Handle pagination
        $TOTALAUCTIONS = $total;

        if(!isset($_GET["PAGE"]) || $_GET["PAGE"] == 1) {
            $OFFSET = 0;
            $PAGE = 1;
        } else {
      $PAGE = $_REQUEST["PAGE"];
            $OFFSET = ($PAGE - 1) * $LIMIT;
        }
        $PAGES = ceil($TOTALAUCTIONS / $LIMIT); 

        $qs = "SELECT * FROM PHPAUCTIONXL_auctions 
                                    WHERE category IN $catalist 
                                    AND starts<=".$NOW."    
                                    AND closed='0' 
                                    AND private='n' 
                                    AND suspended ='0' ";
         if($SETTINGS['adultonly']=='y' && !isset($_SESSION["PHPAUCTION_LOGGED_IN"])){
             $qs .= " AND adultonly='n'";
         }
        if(!empty($_POST['catkeyword'])){
            $qs .= " AND title like '%".addslashes($_POST['catkeyword'])."%' ";
        }
        $qs .= "ORDER BY ends ASC LIMIT ".intval($OFFSET).",".intval($LIMIT);
        $result = mysql_query ($qs);
        /* get list of auctions of this category */
        $auctions_count = 0;
        /* selectd items formatter */
        include $include_path."browseitems.inc.php";

        $TPL_auctions_list_value=browseItems($result);
        $auctions_count=count($TPL_auctions_list_value);

        /*$TPL_auctions_total_value .= "<br />".
        "$MSG_290 $total<br />".
        "$MSG_289 $pages ($lines $MSG_291)<br />".
        $MSG_25_0229;

        for ($i=1; $i<=$pages; ++$i) {
            $TPL_auctions_total_value .=
            ($page==$i) ?
            " $i "  :
            " <a href=\"".$SETTINGS['siteurl']."browse.php?id=".$id."&page=$i\">$i</a> ";
        }
        */
        $TPL_auctions_total_value .="";
        if ($auctions_count==0) {
            $TPL_auctions_total_value = $ERR_114;
        }
    }

    include "header.php";
    include phpa_include("template_browse_header_php.html");
    if ( $subcat_count>0 ) {
        include phpa_include("template_browse_php.html");
    }
    if ($subcat_count==0) {
        include phpa_include("template_auctions_no_cat.html");
    }
    include "footer.php";
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: maybe you should move `$lines = (int)$lines;` above line 175?  In the code you provided, it seems that $lines isn't even defined yet.

Comment: Your code is inconsistent, variables should be in same register, in your case you have variable `$PAGE` and `$page` it is not the same.

Comment: Just do var_dump on variables $page and $lines and see what types they are.

Comment: Where are `$page` & `$lines` defined?

Answer (score 1):

To force the value to be an integer, use `intval`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this code right above those lines:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($lines, $page);exit;
```

what likely happening is your getting a boolean value or null or some other data type multiplying with something it can't multiply with.  that code will tell you the data type of both those variables.

You'll probablly end up enclosing that line in something like this:

```
if(is_numeric($lines) && is_numeric($page)){---your code----}else{$left_limit = --whatever your want as default value--}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$left_limit = ((int)$page-1)*(int)$lines;
```